# ExtJS Textarea - autosave contents on user input

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm an ExtJS newbie and need to send the contents of a ExtJS Textarea to the backend server for saving (autosave facility) as the user types in. Is there a way to do it. I've currently registered a keyup listener to collect the input value as shown below:

```js
items: [{
    xtype: 'textarea',
    id: 'notes',
    anchor: '100%',
    height: 270,
    msgTarget: 'under',
    fieldLabel: 'Note',
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    listeners: {
        'keyup': function(textarea, event) {
            var v= textarea.getValue();
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'buffernote.action',
                params: {value: v}
            })
        }
    }
}
}]
```

Am I in the right direction?

Comment: You should provide us with the Version of ExtJS... 3.x, 4.x

Comment: ExtJS version is 3.3. The code seems to work, but it is too much of overhead. A server call is made for every keystroke. I need to buffer the input before pushing it to the server for saving. How do i set up a buffer ?

Comment: Right-click + paste? Might want to use the `change` event instead? just a thought...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a buffer, put some `ref` to the textarea, then call

```
this.mon(myTextarea, 'keyup', this.onMyTextareaKeyup, this, {buffer: 1000});
```

where `onMyTextareaKeyup` contains the code that you provided to do the request. More info on buffer can be found on [API](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/source/Observable.html#method-Ext.util.Observable-addListener).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I went ahead and implemented the following way due to time constraints, though it may not be the optimal method. var notes = Ext.getCmp('notes');var notesvalue = notes.getRawValue();notesvalue = encodeURIComponent(notesvalue);Ext.Ajax.request({method: 'POST',url:..,params:notesvalue})

Answer (score 1):

You should use two events: one key event and one blur event (blur, change or valid)
Then fill a 'key hit' buffer and write the whole field back if full and reset the buffer. Also write the whole field back if the blur event get executed.

Personally I am using stores that do the write & updates actions for me. So I just need to modify a record in the store.
For that way you just need to play with `record.beginEdit()` & `record.endEdit()`
In ExtJS 4.x they are now using the term Ext.data.Model but it behaves much the same as in ExtJS 3.x

The store will need the option `autoSave: true` otherwise you have to call `save()` on the store to submit any changes.

Comment: This is a Add function. The use case is this. We have a desktop component which embeds the browser application containing this textarea. I need to keep saving the contents of textarea in the user's session so that if the user closes the desktop component the backend application saves the content. To achieve this, I need to implement some sort of autosave functionality. If you have any useful snippet to share, I'll be grateful.

Comment: @Deepak It does not really matter if it run in an isolated environment or the WWW the concept behind it stays the same. You autosave if the keystrokebuffer is full or if the user leave the textarea. Not that the key events catch all keys that are on the keyboard. And you should just use the event to identify a keystroke and not the exact key!